# System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, selectlist

How to solve this error and why this error is occuring

Here is my controller class

```
 public List<SelectOption> getItems()
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://clozer.3spire.net/public/goclozer/country');
        req.setMethod('GET');

        req.setCompressed(false);
        req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

//        String data = '{ "abcd":"xyz","efgh":"djfh" }';
        getAllCountry = (Map<String, String>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Map<String, String>.class);

        List<SelectOption> option = new List<SelectOption>();

         option.add(new SelectOption('0','--None--'));        
        for(String c : getAllCountry.values())
        {
            option.add(new SelectOption(c,c));
        }

        return option;
    }
```

This is the json result

```
{"0":"Aruba","1":"Antigua and Barbuda","2":"United Arab Emirates","3":"Afghanistan","4":"Algeria","5":"Azerbaijan","6":"Albania","7":"Armenia","8":"Andorra","9":"Angola"}
```

Comment: not working @Ratan

Comment: may be try to change setHeader line to req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: @RasMisha error still exist

Comment: @Ratan can we chat is you available

Comment: moin join this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34200/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-ratan

Answer (score 1):

Try the url in a browser. It's not working anymore.

This url `http://clozer.3spire.net/public/goclozer/country` results in this page:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /public/goclozer/country was not found on this server.
```

And this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested URL /public/goclozer/country was not found on this server.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Which fully explains this error `System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<'`

Because you are expecting JSON and you are receiving a 404 page. You will need to find another country list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, is it all code? Where is line that perform request?

```
...
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
...
```

upd.
in your code should be this lines:

```
...
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
res = http.send(req);
getAllCountry = (Map<String, String>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Map<String, String>.class); 
...
```

Comment: yes thats all.and the things is that i use the code before and it worked fine

Comment: @moinkhan it's impossible, because now you have empty body in response. May be you delete this line?

Comment: I just want to get json data from a remote site and then bind them into selectOption.is there any way to do that.

Comment: I understand, but in your code there is no calls to remote site. If you add line res = http.send(req); it must be ok

Comment: now i understand where the problem is.I missed try that line

Comment: now im getting this

Comment: System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2] 
happend now

Comment: @moinkhan put your json

Comment: @kurunve here it is 
{"0":"Aruba","1":"Antigua and Barbuda","2":"United Arab Emirates","3":"Afghanistan","4":"Algeria","5":"Azerbaijan","6":"Albania","7":"Armenia","8":"Andorra","9":"Angola"}

Comment: update you code in topic (may me in upd section). Try to return Content-type that you have previously